# Can't seem to implement an interface from another package

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I started organising my code in packages for simpler reading:

[image]

But can't seem to read interfaces from another package:

[image: Interface1]
[image: Interface2]

Interface code:

```
interface FlowListener {
    void stageWasReached(String tag);
}
```

Comment: drop your interface code

Comment: added interface code

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: look into my ans. It will helpful to you

Comment: The interface should be public as public interface FlowListener {  //your code here }

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only you need to edit your definition with below code

```
public interface FlowListener {
    void stageWasReached(String tag);
}
```

When you  are not mentioned any access specifier then its `default` access specifier means its the `package` level access specifier. Its access in **package and there sub packages only**, `public` this will access from any package.

Comment: @Guy glad to help you :p)

Answer (score 1):

When you declare an class, interface or methods you should declare a access modifier.
This determines from where you are able to use/access the declared interface.

When you don't declare an modifier you are only able to call it from the same package or class.

Oracle has a brilliant tutorial that explains how they work:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html